# Team-viewer disconnected after disconnecting from remote desktop connection, why?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, teamviewer

I want connect to a remote computer (windows server 2012 data center) using team-viewer but remote desktop connection should be opened and connected when I want use my team-viewer for connecting to server team-viewer. if not, team viewer in my computer returns this error:
[image]

After reconnecting to remote using windows remote desktop connection, I can see the screen again without this error. What should I do to connect team-viewer directly to server without active remote desktop connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also could change some settings so that the user is allowed to stay actively logged in (as was the case in previous windows server versions).

The topic below describes a case where idle users were logged out, it was suggested to disable windows settings so that the user session would remain logged in.
https://superuser.com/questions/558920/disable-windows-server-2012-automatic-log-off

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the following reasons.

1. If you RDP (and then you minimize the RDP session, or let go of it)
2. Log out of the user that has the Teamviewer open
3. Let the PC idle out.

**Solution to override this issue.**

INSTALL TEAMVIEWER AS A SERVICE - Turn off your quick-run/quick-support of teamviewer and go to www.teamviewer.com and install the program to launch on boot (that will install it as a service), you will see the option for that during installation. Then that error will never turn up, even if your RDPs. If its already installed, [here](http://ram.kossboss.com/teamviewer-error-screen-captured-moment-due-fast-user-switching/) are the instructions on how to make it run as  a service.